# pgfplots: reduce tick density

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex

I am using `matlab2tikz` to produce plots in latex. The default tick settings produce very dense ticks, making the axes look ugly. I know that I can use something like

```
/pgfplots/xtick={0, 1, ... 3}
```

to manually set the tick positions. However, I am constantly modifying the plot data, and it is annoying to have to go in and change the tick positions manually each time. This is especially annoying when I have subplots where each plot uses a different range, so I can't use the `matlab2tikz` `extraAxisOptions` parameter to change the ticks in MATLAB, since this would apply the same ticks to each subplot.

Here is an example (sorry, I don't know TikZ well enough to make this more minimal):

http://pastebin.com/B2GKyRNb

When I compile this, the y axis has five ticks, and the x axis has ticks every 0.2. I would like to reduce the density in such a way that it scales automatically with the range of the axis as well as the size of the plot (like MATLAB does).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384)

Comment: I know that this here is not an answer, but it may help others visiting this knowledge base: `pgfplots` offers `xtick distance=1` as of version `1.13`. This is also an alternative to `xtick={0,1,...,3}`, although it is only useful in conjunction with a special plot. The answer of @Jake is more general and fits this use-case here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `\pgfplotsset{try min ticks=3}` in your TeX document to allow PGFPlots to use only three ticks for an axis (the default is 4), and `max space between ticks=50pt` to allow more space between the tick marks (the default is 35):

[image]

Comment: +1. I have setup all of my PGFPlots like this. I find the default settings can look a little bit cramped sometimes.

Comment: According to the pgfplots documentation, you have to leave out the `pt`, i.e., `max space between ticks=50`.

Comment: This solution is gold! I was stuck with the limited number of ticks in smaller graphs.