# pgfplots: How to fix the number of yticks?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

With `max space between ticks=` it is possible to set space between ticks, but I would like to setup the number of ticks, so all my graphs will look similar. I would be happy with 4 ticks, so if y vary from 0 to 100, I would have ticks at 20, 40, 60, 80. Is it possible to automate this without needing to customize for each graph?

Comment: If one of your graphs ranges from 0 to 20, what numbers would you want?

Comment: The values are not important, for me. I'm interested in the visual effect of having same number of yticks. Between 0 and 20: 4,8,12,16

Comment: @PeterSenna: So if it was from 0 to 19, would you want 3.8, 7.6, 11.4, 15.2? That is, they shouldn't be four "nice" numbers, but they should divide the axis range into five equal sections? Or would you want 0, 5, 10, 15 in that case? (Personally, I think that using non-nice numbers, even things like 0, 4, 8, are not going to be very helpful for your readers, though)

Comment: @PeterSenna: By the way, you should use `@Jake` in your comments when replying to me, otherwise I won't get notified.

Comment: @Jake, I would prefer nicer numbers like 0, 5, 10 and 15. I'm dealing with numbers like 30000 and 187000, so there are room for approximation...

Comment: @PeterSenna: I don't think the desired behaviour is specified accurately enough to be implemented. PGFPlots already chooses "nice" tick numbers, but constraining it to a fixed number is inevitably going to lead to either non-nice numbers (e.g. 0, 6.67, 13.33, 10 in the case of a range of 0 to 20), or to arbitrary leaving out of ticks that logically should be there (4, 8, 12, 16: Why aren't 0 and 20 labelled if they are part of the range? What do you do if it ranges from -1 to 20?). Maybe using the approach from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96352/2552 to allow more types of "nice" ticks, to..

Comment: ..gether with `try min ticks=3` and `max space between ticks=<some value that's 1/4 of your axis height>` would already get you results that are typically close enough to four ticks to be satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use xtick and xtickslabels options:

```
xtick={1,2,3,4},
xticklabels={a,b,c,d},
```

xticks contains the position (in your case: 20, 40. 60 and 80) of your ticks and xticklabels contains the labels.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6} 
\pgfplotsset{ every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}

\begin{document} 
\footnotesize 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=6cm,
height=6cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-0.8444, xmax=0.8223,
xtick={-0.8444,-0.4277,-0.0110,0.4056,0.8223},
xticklabels={-0.8444,-0.4277,-0.0110,0.4056,0.8223}]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This requires customizing each plot though, which the OP didn't want to.

Comment: My problem is that I have 40 different graphs. I want to add the same text string to all 40 graphs and have 4 yticks on them...